# After updating the Red Hat server kernel to latest version it still shows as old version

Tags: rhel, kernel, patch

I have updated the kernel on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) from **2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64** to **2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64** and as per Red Hat documentation https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078  kernel  version 2.6.32-642 will update the release to RHEL 6.8. However if you look below it still shows as 6.7 (Santiago). I am not sure why the difference ? I have also rebooted the server after the kernel was updated.

```
[root@test-dev-001-par user1]# uname -a
Linux test-dev-001-par user1.hello.world.net 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 6 14:54:05 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@test-dev-001-par user1]# uptime
16:02:35 up  5:16,  1 user,  load average: 0.43, 0.34, 0.33

[root@test-dev-001-par user1]#  cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

[root@test-dev-001-par user1]#  cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Comment: Both the old and new version are installed, I bet.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, you *are* running `2.6.32-642.1.1` based on your `uname` output:

```
Linux test-dev-001-par user1.hello.world.net 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 6 14:54:05 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However, the `/etc/redhat-release` file isn't related the kernel.

You've only done a partial update; to update to the complete RedHat 6.8 version you need to run a *full* update

```
# yum update
```

This will, amongst other things, update the `redhat-release` package which is where `/etc/redhat-release` gets installed from.

See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/637583 for more details.

Comment: thank you however i want to avoid doing a yum update from updating everything. Also, will that not update it to Red Hat 7 ? Is there a way to just check how  redhat-release gets updated since i just learnt that simply updating kernal won't help.

Comment: `yum update` will stay within the RedHat major version; so it will take a 6.7 to 6.8.  It won't jump major versions.  If you do _not_ do a `yum update` then you are not at 6.8.